The animation only works in one direction in flutter AnimatedWidget
Everyone here.
I made the toggle into an animation.
And I'm looking forward to acting as an animation when I move in both directions.
However, the animation only works when moving from right to left as shown in the screen below.

Is there a wonderful developer who can help me? I'm desperate ㅠㅠ
Below is the full source of that Widget.
class ShipModeToggleWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final bool isChecked;
  final void Function() toggleChangeEvent;
  const ShipModeToggleWidget({
    super.key,
    required this.isChecked,
    required this.toggleChangeEvent,
  });

  @override
  State<ShipModeToggleWidget> createState() => _ShipModeToggleWidgetState();
}

class _ShipModeToggleWidgetState extends State<ShipModeToggleWidget>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  final Duration _duration = const Duration(milliseconds: 300);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final SvgIconAssetName asset = widget.isChecked
        ? SvgIconAssetName.ship_toggle
        : SvgIconAssetName.user_toggle;
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: widget.toggleChangeEvent,
      child: Stack(
        clipBehavior: Clip.none,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          AnimatedContainer(
            duration: _duration,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            width: 81,
            height: 31,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: widget.isChecked ? AppTheme.hitup_blue : AppTheme.blue_050,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
            ),
            child: AnimatedDefaultTextStyle(
              style: TextStyle(
                color: widget.isChecked ? AppTheme.white : AppTheme.blue_300,
                fontSize: 16,
              ),
              duration: _duration,
              child: Text(widget.isChecked ? "선장" : "일반"),
            ),
          ),
          AnimatedPositioned(
            right: widget.isChecked ? -15 : 81 - 20,
            duration: _duration,
            child: Container(
              width: 39,
              height: 39,
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: AppTheme.white,
                shape: BoxShape.circle,
                border: Border.all(
                  color: widget.isChecked
                      ? AppTheme.hitup_blue
                      : AppTheme.blue_050,
                  width: 2,
                ),
              ),
              child: SvgAssetIconWidget(
                size: 20,
                svgIconAssetName: asset,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

If you need more information, please request it!!

Your ShipModeToggleWidget seems nothing wrong, I assume the issue relates to how you use this widget, not the widget itself. Maybe the parent widget is re-init -> cause your toggle is re-created too, at that time animation won't work. You can add log to the initState and build method at toggle widget and see what happened
